# Gingerbread keyboard glitch - double letters

Tags: javascript, android, html, browser, android-2.3-gingerbread

Anyone knows some fix to html/js so the glitch will gone?

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14755

http://androidforums.com/threads/android-keyboard-issue-double-letters.278325/

Basically it doubles first letter of every word when you type something. (for sure it happens when use stock browser in android gingerbread.

Thanks for help.

EDIT quote from one of websites:

> Let me give you an example by typing "hello there". Upon finishing the
>   word "hello", I would press SPACE followed by "t". If I'm typing
>   really fast and the SPACE is still being pressed while typing the "t"
>   (multitouch), "t" will appear, BUT without an underline. Then the "t"
>   would be duplicated when you type the letter "h", resulting in "hello
>   tthere" when you finish them. And sometimes when you're typing even
>   faster, you'd also see "hello ththere"